# MPCharts add margin to LineDataSet label

Tags: android, kotlin, mpandroidchart

I am using `MPCharts` and cannot figure out how to move the label for the one dataset that I have.

In the screenshot below, I want to move the `Time Of Day` text about 10dp down so that it is not so close to the x axis. (**Not the x axis point labels**)

[image]

Comment: `lineChart.legend.yOffset` does nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use setExtraBottomOffset which is by default 15

```
 chart.setExtraBottomOffset(30);
```

Comment: Verified and working, though Kotlin expects a float: `30f`